# NHibernate - Poor performance with Memcached

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, caching, memcached

I installed Membase and created a new memcached bucket. In the settings, I chose to setup a dedicated port with port ID of 1111 for simplicity sake.

In my web.config I have this:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="memcache" type="NHibernate.Caches.MemCache.MemCacheSectionHandler, NHibernate.Caches.MemCache" requirePermission="false" />
  ...
</configSections>

<memcache>
  <memcached host="127.0.0.1" port="1111" />
</memcache>
```

In my NHibernate config section:

```
<property name="cache.use_query_cache" >true</property>
<property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="cache.provider_class">NHibernate.Caches.MemCache.MemCacheProvider, NHibernate.Caches.MemCache</property>
```

In each of my NHibernate class mappings, I have this at the top right after the class tag:

```
<cache usage="nonstrict-read-write" />
```

When I run this, my queries are an order of magnitude slower than if I was using Syscache. Is there anything that looks wrong? I am fairly new to setting something like this up.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't seem to have any obvious problems in your configuration. Syscache is using the ASP.NET cache provider and there is no network communication between your app and the cache, but still it should in theory only be a little faster than memcached running on localhost (this assuming you have enough memory to avoid swapping ).

You might want to try to run your app with a profiler to see where the time is actually spent. Also you should make sure that memcached is actually used to returned the cached queries and no sql query is issued - log the sql and expect to see it only the first time the query is executed.

I'm using [membase](http://www.membase.org/) with a [memcached bucket](http://techzone.couchbase.com/wiki/display/membase/Membase+for+Memcached+Users) and the [enyim memcached client](http://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhcontrib/trunk/src/NHibernate.Caches/EnyimMemcached/), with a configuration similar to yours and i'm very pleased with the performance. The membase also provides a nice administration console where you can see various useful statistics about cache usage.

Also, not related to your question but, make sure you understand how query caching works before enableing it. See this [two](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/08/21/TheSecretLifeOfNHibernatesCaches.aspx) [posts](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/24/nhibernate-2nd-level-cache.aspx) from ayende.

Comment: Interesting. So you are not using the disk based persistance of membase?  Does it still 'replicate' in that configuration?  I wonder how performance compares to memcached in this use.

Comment: I'm not using any of the membase specific features. Only the ability to run a memcached bucket. Behind the scene membase runs a memcached deamon so i would expect performance and functionality to be the same as running standalone memcached. I made this choice because membase installs in 5 minutes, configures in other 5 minutes and the console provides a nice way to view statistics about memcahced.

Comment: I am actually using the membase server and my buckets are memcached buckets. I fire up my NHibernate Profiler and the same queries and cache calls are coming in, but instead of them being 70ms, they are now 20-25s each. How are you using the Enyim Memcached Client? I have only ever seen the use of the memcacheprovider used to wire into the config.

Comment: I have this in the config file, and nothing else specific to caching in the application: <property name='cache.provider_class'>NHibernate.Caches.EnyimMemcached.MemCacheProvider, NHibernate.Caches.EnyimMemcached</property>. Also my entities have <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/> so that should not be a problem.

Comment: 20-25s is way way to much for a query, so i suspect your problem is either related to the cache provider, either something unrelated. You should try a clr profiler ( red gate ants profiler , dot trace ) to see where the time is spent.

Comment: Did you have to do any additional configs outside of the NHibernate config section? I know the examples with the Enyim.Caching have something like this:
`<enyim.com>
    <memcached>
      <servers>
        <!-- put your own server(s) here-->
        <add address="localhost" port="1111" />
      </servers>
      <socketPool minPoolSize="10" maxPoolSize="100" connectionTimeout="00:00:10" deadTimeout="00:02:00" />
    </memcached>
  </enyim.com>`

Comment: Then you add this to your configSections: `<sectionGroup name="enyim.com">
      <section name="memcached" type="Enyim.Caching.Configuration.MemcachedClientSection, Enyim.Caching" />
    </sectionGroup>`